# Memoization of member function of Kotlin data class

Tags: functional-programming, kotlin

In the following Kotlin example, I'd like to "memoize" (cache the result of) the member function `matches`:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern

data class MyDataClass(val name: String = "John Doe",
                       val description: String = "Famous person") {

    //TODO memoize this
    fun matches(searchTerm: String): Boolean {
        println("Calculating...")
        return name.matches("(?i).*${Pattern.quote(searchTerm)}.*".toRegex())
                || description.matches("(?i).*${Pattern.quote(searchTerm)}.*".toRegex())
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val myData = MyDataClass()
    println(myData.matches("John"))
    println(myData.matches("John"))
    println(myData.matches("John"))
    println(myData.matches("Famous"))
    println(myData.matches("Famous"))
    println(myData.matches("Famous"))    
}
```

As far as I can see, Kotlin <= 1.1 doesn't support memoization. Of course, you can write your own memoization function or use a library like e.g. https://github.com/MarioAriasC/funKTionale

Using funKTionale, I don't have to write my own memoization function and came to this solution. Unfortunately it looks "boilerplatey":

```
import org.funktionale.memoization.memoize
import java.util.regex.Pattern

data class MyMemoizedDataClassV1(val name: String = "John Doe",
                                 val description: String = "Famous person") {

    private val memoizedMatches: (String, String, String) -> Boolean =
            { name: String, description: String, searchTerm: String ->
                println("Calculating...")
                name.matches("(?i).*${Pattern.quote(searchTerm)}.*".toRegex())
                        || description.matches("(?i).*${Pattern.quote(searchTerm)}.*".toRegex())
            }.memoize()

    fun matches(searchTerm: String): Boolean {
        return memoizedMatches(name, description, searchTerm)
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val myData = MyMemoizedDataClassV1()
    println(myData.matches("John"))
    println(myData.matches("John"))
    println(myData.matches("John"))
    println(myData.matches("Famous"))
    println(myData.matches("Famous"))
    println(myData.matches("Famous"))
}
```

I think of **a nicer looking solution** like

```
data class MyDataClass(val name: String = "John Doe",
                       val description: String = "Famous person") {

    fun matches(searchTerm: String): Boolean {
        println("Calculating...")
        return name.matches("(?i).*${Pattern.quote(searchTerm)}.*".toRegex())
                || description.matches("(?i).*${Pattern.quote(searchTerm)}.*".toRegex())
    }.memoize() //TODO how?
}
```

But, how to achieve this?

Comment: Does memoization means caching result?

Comment: @Joshua, yes. Thanks for the comment. I edited the question and added  "caching the result".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove a lot of the boilerplate from your Funktionale code:

```
data class MyMemoizedDataClassV1(val name: String = "John Doe",
                                 val description: String = "Famous person") {

    val matches = { searchTerm: String ->
        println("Calculating...")
        name.matches("(?i).*${Pattern.quote(searchTerm)}.*".toRegex())
           || description.matches("(?i).*${Pattern.quote(searchTerm)}.*".toRegex())
    }.memoize()

}
```

You have access to `name` and `description` from the data class in your lambda, so you don't have to pass them as parameters. Having them as parameters would make the memoize-function use them in the key to lookup the answer, but this is useless because they never change (as they are defined with `val`).

Also, because `matches` has the type `(String) -> Boolean`, you can just expose the function-property directly in your data class, instead of creating another function that calls it. Finally, I removed some types that the compiler can infer.

Answer (score 1):

`a` and `b` are `val`, so you can assign the result to a `val`

```
data class MyDataClass(val a: Int = 1,
                       val b: Int = 2) {
    val sum = a + b
}
```

If the calculation is expensive, you can use lazy to delay calculation.

```
data class MyDataClass(val a: Int = 1,
                        val b: Int = 2) {
    val sum: Int by lazy {
        a + b
    }
}
```

Edit: New answer for edited question

```
interface StringMatchable {
    fun matches(searchTerm: String): Boolean
}

data class MyDataClass(val name: String = "John Doe",
                       val description: String = "Famous person") : StringMatchable by 
CacheStringMatchable({
    searchTerm ->
    name.matches("(?i).*${Pattern.quote(searchTerm)}.*".toRegex())
            || description.matches("(?i).*${Pattern.quote(searchTerm)}.*".toRegex())
})

class CacheStringMatchable(private val function: (String) -> Boolean) : StringMatchable {
    private val map: MutableMap<String, Boolean> = mutableMapOf()
    override fun matches(searchTerm: String): Boolean {
        return map.computeIfAbsent(searchTerm, function)
    }
}
```

To delegate a method, it is only possible by interface currently. So, it probably cannot be written in generic way (i.e. 1 cache class for all).

Edit2: If this is the only class need `matches()`, then here is a simpler answer

```
data class MyDataClass(val name: String = "John Doe",
                       val description: String = "Famous person") {
    private val map: MutableMap<String, Boolean> = mutableMapOf()
    fun matches(searchTerm: String): Boolean {
        return map.computeIfAbsent(searchTerm, {
            searchTerm ->
            name.matches("(?i).*${Pattern.quote(searchTerm)}.*".toRegex())
                    || description.matches("(?i).*${Pattern.quote(searchTerm)}.*".toRegex())
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Joshua, excellent solution for the given example. I actually over-simplied the example. In my real world use case the member function takes 1 or more parameters to calculate something using the internal state. I have to adjust the question or open up a second question with a "tricker" example...

Comment: @Peti I can edit the answer if you give more details =)

Comment: I changed the example. Now the member function has 1 parameter.

Comment: @Peti see the  new answer